# Generic Stored Procedure Endpoint for WebApi with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, stored-procedures, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a generic stored procedure end point for our WebApi which is running EF 6.

The idea is that we can call a stored procedure by passing the name and parameters across. I have the following;

```
[HttpPost]
[CustomAuthFilter]
[Route("storedproc/{storedproc}")]
public IHttpActionResult RunStoredProcedure(string storedproc, Dictionary<string,string> parameters)
{
    var response = Repo.RunSP(storedproc, parameters);
    return Ok(response);
}
```

where the RunSP method is;

```
public static string RunSP(string storedProcedure,  Dictionary<string,string> parameters)
{
    using (var dataContext = new dbContext())
    {
        var queryString = new StringBuilder();
        queryString.Append(storedProcedure);
        queryString.Append(" ");

        int count = 0;

        var param = new List<string>();

        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (var pair in parameters)
            {
                queryString.Append("@" + pair.Key + " = {" + count + "}");

                count++;

                if (count < parameters.Count)
                    queryString.Append(",");

                param.Add(pair.Value);
            }
        }

        var json = dataContext.Database.SqlQuery<string>(queryString.ToString(), param);
        return json;
    }
}
```

Now the issue is with seralising the return to an anonymous json string at the end? is this possible and if so how? As the method is generic I cant serialise to a specific class?

If I have to use something else other than EF to get this functionality what would the best approach be?

Comment: From security point of view, this is not a good idea.  I can pass a string "select 'drop table ' + Table_name from information_schema.tables where table_type = 'base table'" then pass the result to your api.

Comment: Hi Jules, The Bobby tables issue is a concern but the endpoint has a security filter on it and is only given access to authorised dbs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will not be possible using EF easily. Someone actually tried doing it I found it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/839640/Unknown-Class-Dynamically-Generated-at-runtime-for). You can go raw yourself and use `SqlDataReader` to populate, serialize and then return you data as string like done [here](http://anexinetmobility.blogspot.com/2013/09/returning-dynamic-data-with-entity.html). The easiest solution would be to use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) to get your results fetched as `dynamic` followed by serializing it using [Json.net](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json) and return it.

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    var result = await con.QueryAsync("QueryString", new { param = "param" });
    return JsonConver.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I thought so, so I ended up just using ado.net to solve this.